# jQuery: sorting array of object according to values between 2 separators

Tags: jquery, arrays, sorting, javascript-objects

Is it possible to sort an array of objects according to two columns but only taking account the values between 2 separators ?

I would like for instance to sort in a descending way by size and then by surface but only by taking into account the value between "-" and "-".

Just like if I had:

```
array=[
    {surface: "200", size: "Medium"},
    {surface: "200", size: "Small"},
    {surface: "100", size: "Big"},
    {surface: "300", size: "Medium"},
]
```

Sorted into this:

```
array=[
    {surface: "500", size: "Small"},
    {surface: "300", size: "Medium"},
    {surface: "200", size: "Medium"},
    {surface: "100", size: "Big"}

]
```

But with this array instead:

```
array=[
    {surface: "9809-200-45450", size: "fghddffz-Medium-yuifgghj"},
    {surface: "1212-200-43483", size: "sdfsfsdf-Small-fgdfgd"},
    {surface: "2323-100-43264", size: "gdfgsdfg-Big-sddfgdfg"},
    {surface: "9809-300-45450", size: "qdfgqdfg-Medium-hjkghj"},
]
```

And getting it sorted like this:

```
array=[
    {surface: "1212-500-43483", size: "sdfsfsdf-Small-fgdfgd"},
    {surface: "9809-300-45450", size: "qdfgqdfg-Medium-hjkghj"},
    {surface: "9809-200-45450", size: "fghddffz-Medium-yuifgghj"},
    {surface: "2323-100-43264", size: "gdfgsdfg-Big-sddfgdfg"}
]
```

With a standard sorting, I would have done this:

```
array.sort(function(a, b){
    if(a.size == b.size){
        return (a.surface < b.surface)  ? 1 : (a.surface  > b.surface ) ? -1 : 0;
    }
    else{
        return (a.size < b.size) ? 1 : -1;
    }
});
```

But I have no idea how to substitute "a/b.surface" or "a/b.size" with only a portion of their value and not their whole value.
I'm not even sure it's possible that way.

Any advice in the right direction would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: `a.surface` -> `a.surface.split("-")[1]`

Comment: So this is not about sorting but how to get the relevant info from a string? -> `String.prototype.split()`

Comment: No I know how to get the relevant info from a string using the split function. But I can't see how to substitute this portion if string afterwards so that the whole array is sorted accordingly. So yes, it's about sorting.

Comment: Thank you very much freedom-m.  I had the split function but couldn't reconcile this with the rest.  I was looking way too far but your answer is simple and elegant. Thanks to both of you actually. Take care..